# Accelerating the for/if loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to fix temperature values in a dataframe based in measurements from meteorological stations.
Some values were wrong collected (>100°C) and I wanna drop these rows from my dataframe. The df has 700k rows and I have to create a new column dataframe.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(!is.na(df$temperature[i]>100)){
    df$temperature2[i] <- df$temperature[i]/10
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to drop these cases from your data, simply do `df_new <- df[df$temperature <100,]`.

Comment: `R` is vectorized so you do not need a for loop to create a new variable.

Comment: `df$temperature2 <- ifelse(df$temperature>100, df$temperature/100, df$temperature)`

Comment: `df$temperature3 <- df$temperature` then do  `df$temperature3[df$temperature3>100] <- df$temperature3/10`

Comment: Here's an explanation of why these other approaches will work much better in R: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df[df$temperature <= 100,] %>%
  mutate(temperature2 = temperature/10)`
```